# How to create a user who need to input root password to gain root access level

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

i tried to create user "support" with password and listed on etc/sudoers under root account :

```
#User Privilege Specification
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
support ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

But whenever i use command "sudo su" it just ask the support password and gain the root access. i want the user "support" use root password (not his password) to gain root access.

this is some detail information that what i want :

some VM had been setup by another Sys Admin and when i use command "sudo su" and put support's password it comes notification

```
user support is not allowed to execute '/bin/su' as root on localhost-server
```

thank you very much

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you describe is typical for debian based distributions, others follow others setups. Once you think about it you will agree that this actually does make sense from a security point of view: the root password does not have to get shared, so it is not forgotten and does not have to be re-shared with every change. Instead sudo allows a fine grained selection of what single users can do or not, so permissions can also be retracted which is not possible if you use the traditional approach to share the root password.

That said I suggest you start reading the documentation, namely the manual pages of the sudo command suite. At the end of `man sudo_root` you will find the exact answer of what you ask:

It *is* possible to "revert" the behavior to the traditional approach by setting a root password, but that is discouraged for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a code-related question.

Then don't use sudo. simply use `su root` or `su` (which without arguments implies user root), and enter the root password.

Comment: of course thats why i use tag linux and ubuntu.

no sir, some people that use "support" account always use command "sudo su" and i dont want they gain root access unless know the root password

Comment: Well... sudo is used to execute a command as another user *without* knowing the password of the user you want to execute command as, 

If you know the password, you can use "su" without sudo.